# *** glibc detected *** : free() : invalid pointer c++

Tags: c++, memory, profiling, release, gprof

I'm having some trouble when trying to execute the following code :https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/facedetect.cpp

With this modification in memory allocation:

```
for(;;)
{
 //   IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        IplImage *iplImg = NULL ;
        iplImg = new IplImage ;
        iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture);
   frame = cv::cvarrToMat(iplImg);
    if( frame.empty() )
        break;
    if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
        frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
    else
        flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );
   // delete iplImg;
    free(iplImg);
    iplImg = NULL;
    detectAndDraw( frameCopy, cascade, nestedCascade, scale, tryflip );

    if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
        goto _cleanup_;
}
```

***error**   glibc detected  **: ./facedetect free() : invalid pointer c++***

I have used gprof to know the time executions of my functions 
[image: here is the output of gprof]
I want to reduce the time spent on release and detectAndDraw functions :p
NB : is manual memory management in c++ better than automatic one ??
+ using delete instead of free didn't solve my problem
thanks for your help :)

Comment: I haven't found an answer to my question why its duplicate :p @paddy

Comment: I didn't mark your question as duplicate.  I just edited your question to make it readable.

Comment: The answer, however, is that you cannot use `free` to release memory allocated with `new`.  Instead, you must use `delete`.

Comment: ok thank you , but i'm getting the same error when using delete too !

Comment: iplImg = new IplImage ;    iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture);  The problem is with the second statement. First it causes a memory leak because you loose the pointer to the newly allocated object. And then you have the runtime error because you are calling delete for something which is not a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: @Pandrei ok thank you ...  can you suggest me a solution for that :p

Comment: @user3530803 yes; get rid of the second line. I don't know what you are trying to do but clearly the approach is wrong. Maybe post a question and and explain what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @Pandrei do you mean  iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture); ? it's the most important part of the program ... this function get a fame from the camera

Comment: @user3530803 as previously said, I don't know what the code is supposed to do. Based on what you've shown, I told you where the problem is. If you want more - raise the question and include a detailed description; maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: I looked at the code you linked, and compared to your changes, then I looked at the OpenCV documentation.  You must NOT free the pointer returned by `cvQueryFrame`.  That memory is managed by the `CvCapture` structure, and is most likely part of a large buffer.  If you added a `free` or `delete` to some code and it started crashing, your first suspicion should have been that it's your fault! =)  The very next thing to do is consult the documentation for the function providing that pointer to find out whether you own the return value.

Comment: More info here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read

Comment: @Pandrei the program is about face detection using opencv and rasperry pi with the camera module ... when i run the program it's runs slowly => so i have overclocked the raspberry pi to 1GHZ and it seemed to speed up the execution but i want to optimize it more so that the code can be run fast enough to detect multiple faces in a little period of time ... so anything about code optimization can help me ?  thanks :)